# Execute command to a Python script from separate Python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, pyside2

I'm trying to send a command from one python script to another running in terminal.

I'm running two python scripts on an RPi running Raspbian. The first script is a loop that waits for the user to enter a number and adds it to a total. The second script uses PySide2 to print a number when a QPushButton is released.

How can i make it so that the function that runs when the QPushButton is released, sends a command (or variable) into the waiting first script and executes it?

I've read some things about using `subprocess.call` and `os.system` but i'm not really sure what i'm doing with these commands, or if they're appropriate for what i want to do.

First script:

```
x = 0
while x < 10:
    y = int(input("enter number:"))
    x += y
    print(x)

print("x is ten!")
```

Second script:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.btn = QPushButton("test")

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.btn.released.connect(self.btnpress)

    def btnpress(self):
        print(1)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: As both the scripts are in python, can you just `import` the second script in the first one for ececution rather that using `subprocess.call` or `os.system` ?

Comment: If i do that i must wait for the first script to finish running before the second script starts and for the button to appear.

Comment: @Welshhobo I don't understand why you deleted your previous post since I was working on an answer that implemented the use of the eventloop that uses dbus with Qt that IMHO was more elegant but good anyway in this case I already proposed a solution according to what you provide: Use QProcess .

Comment: @eyllanesc Ahh sorry, i thought the script relied on a bunch of modules needing to be installed first so i figured that it would be simpler and i'd get more answers posting a simpler example. If you still have that it would be really handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run a script and send information through stdin then in Qt the best option is to use QProcess:

```py
import os.path
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import QProcess
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QSpinBox, QVBoxLayout, QWidget

CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.btn = QPushButton("test")
        self.spinbox = QSpinBox()

        self.process = QProcess()
        self.process.readyReadStandardError.connect(self.handle_readyReadStandardError)
        self.process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(
            self.handle_readyReadStandardOutput
        )
        self.process.setProgram(sys.executable)
        script_path = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, "script.py")
        self.process.setArguments([script_path])
        self.process.start()

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.spinbox)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.btn.released.connect(self.btnpress)

    def btnpress(self):
        number = self.spinbox.value()

        msg = "{}\n".format(number)
        self.process.write(msg.encode())

    def handle_readyReadStandardError(self):
        print(self.process.readAllStandardError().data().decode())

    def handle_readyReadStandardOutput(self):
        print(self.process.readAllStandardOutput().data().decode())


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

**Note:** You don't have to run the script in a second shell as the script itself starts it.

Comment: Thats working fantastic, will try to implement it into my main program and see how it goes. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for this its been a massive help. As mentioned i'm trying to get it to work with a bluetooth controller that uses dbus. I'm having trouble getting it to read the `print` outputs from the script. I've done some reading and found that the `readAllStandardOutput` method stores into a QByteArray. I'm reading the documentation on this but i can't get my head around how it works. AFAIK this doesn't work like a regular list/array does it? i.e. i can't just `print` each "cell" in a loop to simulate an output. Is it worth writing a new question with a simplified version of my actual program?

Answer (score 0):

Subprocesses make sense when there is a clear parent/child relationship. This sounds more like you have two independent agents which occasionally need to communicate. There are various inter-process communication (IPC) mechanisms depending on your needs, the most basic being signals, where either process can send the other a single bit of information to notify it that some event occurred. For more complex needs, set up shared memory, or talk over a socket or a FIFO.

Answer (score -1):

i think that you have to add a third party, like:

1. DATABASE
2. REDIS
3. File

but you cannot not send a command from a running script to another running script,
because the CLI script wait command from his shell only.
greetings